# How to check the Parameters of an URL using Selenium

Tags: selenium, python-3.x

I need help in checking the parameters in an url using Selenium Python.

Problem: I had an URL 
For Ex: http://www.test.com/hi13docs?layouttype=Hello&env=prod&id=16&sitename=US&vendorid=testing&plid=0ENG&os=windows

The above URL is after redirection. So, i want to check the above parameters like Sitename, id, Vendorid values are correct or not (Provided the above values US, 16, testing are correct).

Any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use something along the lines of

```
url = selenium.getLocation();
```

Then split the string and compare the parameters to what is in the string variable.